# Evaluating line integrals in the plane

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral $$\int xy\,dx+(x+y)\,dy$$ along the curve $y=x^2$ from $(-1, 1)$ to $(2, 4)$.

I tried finding $dx$ and $dy$ and substituting that into the original integral, along with $y=x^2$. But I don't get the right answer.

I've looked online for similar problems and I saw that someone multiplied the original integral (with $y=x^2$ substituted in), with $|\textbf{v}(t)|$.

But I'm having trouble understanding how to find the parameterization, $\textbf{r}(t)$. Could someone take me through the steps of solving this problem and finding $\textbf{r}(t)$ in particular? Thank you so much!

Comment: When evaluating a line integral, you want to get everything in terms of one variable. That variable is often the parameter used to describe the curve, but not always. For a curve as simple as the one you have, you don't.

Comment: So in this case, would I just find dx and dy and substitute that into the integral? (Also substituting in y=x^2) Then would I just solve that integral?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. You have to remember than on the curve $y=x^2$. I have taken x as the independent variable and proceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int xy dx + \int (x+y) dy
$$
Along $y=x^2$, from (-1,1) to (2,4). 
In the first integral, simply set $y=x^2$ and the limits of x are (-1,2).

In the second integral, if you try to use $x=\sqrt{y}$ you'll have a problem because the range of x is from -1 to 2, not 1 to 2.

$$
\int_{1}^{4} \sqrt{y} dy + \int_{1}^{4} y dy
$$

won't work.

Using x as the independent variable works, though. In the second integral, simply set $y=x^2$ and the limits of x are (-1,2).

$$
\int_{-1}^{2} (x + x^2) 2x dx
$$

you can easily proceed from this point on.

Comment: For the second integral, even though it was originally dy, we don't use the y coordinates as the integration limits? (Just making sure)

Comment: @Karen I've just made an edit to show you why we use x in this case. For any x you can find y, but in this range there are two values of x for some y's.